# Can't get images to align with Gutenberg editor

Tags: images

I am setting up a new site for a non-profit. The theme I chose uses the new Gutenberg only. I would like an image on the left and description on the right, with another image below that, with the accompanying description to its right. No matter what I do in the editor, I can't move the lower image down and to justify left. I have screen shots of the editor page and what it looks like on the site.[image: site][image: in the editor]

Comment: Looks like a float (CSS) problem.

Comment: What do I do? And how would I explain this to the scared of computers folks who will be taking over the website once I set it up. Doesn't look like this new editor will be "as easy as changing a Word file, " which is what I usually tell people who want to be able to just change the words on their static pages.

Comment: I just learned to transform the image into a media and text image, this is allowing me to put the content next to the image. But it's very limiting compared to the old editor.

Answer (score 0):

#### CSS

In *Customize -> Additional CSS*, add the following code:

```
.clearflow {
    clear: both;
}
figure.alignleft {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

#### Blocks

Insert blocks in the following order:

```
    Image
    Paragraph
    ...
    Paragraph
    Image
    Paragraph
    ...
    Paragraph
```

Select *Image* block, and on its toolbar, select *Align left* icon. *In Advanced -> Additional CSS Class* section, add `clearflow` class.

Repeat this for every *Image* block.